# How Does GetStringType Cause a Deadlock in Dll Main?

Tags: windows, winapi, deadlock

I'm looking at an application which hangs on Server 2016 but runs find on Server 2008 R2. I have traced it to a hang caused by deadlock when a particular DLL loads. Analysing the DLL (I don't have the source code) I can see that it violates the guideline [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices?fbclid=IwAR3ffNnUodpDw99JYqfcC_561Y9RNBM96QzKdN17Jj21TcNmY7PgY_fXMzs)

- Call GetStringTypeA, GetStringTypeEx, or GetStringTypeW (either
  directly or indirectly). This can cause a deadlock or a crash

Specifically it calls GetStringTypeW from DllMain.

I'm trying to understand how this function can cause deadlocks in DllMain.

Comment: You already know how it causes deadlocks. It tries to claim the loader lock.

Comment: I see nothing happening on Win10, but Server marches to a very different drummer.  Probably [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin).  You'll only get guesses here, create a minidump of the deadlocked process to get a fact.

Answer (score 0):

> Your DllMain function runs inside the loader lock, one of the few
>   times the OS lets you run code while one of its internal locks is
>   held. This means that you must be extra careful not to violate a lock
>   hierarchy in your DllMain; otherwise, you are asking for a deadlock. (Refer to "[Another reason not to do anything scary in your DllMain: Inadvertent deadlock](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040128-00/?p=40853)")

`DllMain` is called while the loader-lock is held, so if `GetStringType` acquires the loader lock, deadlock appears.

> Significant restrictions are imposed on the functions that can be
>   called within DllMain. As such, DllMain is designed to perform minimal
>   initialization tasks, by using a small subset of the Microsoft®
>   Windows® API. **You cannot call any function in DllMain that directly or
>   indirectly tries to acquire the loader lock.** Otherwise, you will
>   introduce the possibility that your application deadlocks or crashes.

We can't see source code of [`GetStringType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getstringtypea) function. It is suggested to follow [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices?fbclid=IwAR3ffNnUodpDw99JYqfcC_561Y9RNBM96QzKdN17Jj21TcNmY7PgY_fXMzs#general-best-practices).

Comment: The asker knows this, and links to the same MSDN docs as you do. The question is, why does this function require the loader lock? Your answer appears to be, "I don't know.'

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If GetStringType don't acquire a loader lock, there is no possibility to cause a deadlock. Since the document explicitly state call `GetStringTypeA`, `GetStringTypeEx`, or `GetStringTypeW` (either directly or indirectly) can cause a deadlock we need to follow. And `GetStringType` source code is not exposed, if you know, any sharing is appreciate.

Comment: As I said, all this is stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function from `DllMain` that will (directly or indirectly) attempt to load another module is going to deadlock.

Module loading is serialized. The system uses a lock to ensure that at any given time no more than a single DLL entry point is entered. If you are calling `LoadLibrary` (directly or indirectly) from your DLL entry point, you are holding the loader lock. `LoadLibrary` will attempt to acquire the loader lock itself prior to calling into the module's entry point. So while your code is waiting for `LoadLibrary` to return, `LoadLibrary` is waiting for the lock you are holding. That's a deadlock.

This is likely the reason why calling `GetStringType` from `DllMain` deadlocks. Without access to source code I cannot verify this, though. You may be able to find evidence by enabling [loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps).